# entity manager query order by select count

Tags: java, sql, jpa, entity

сам sql запрос:

```
select t from Product t  where t.category.id=2  ORDER BY (SELECT count(oi.id) FROM OrderItem oi WHERE t.id = oi.product.id) DESC
```

когда я пытаюсь передать это в entityManager.createQuery(..); то получаю ошибку, потому что он в упор не хочет в ORDER BY  видеть какие-либо селекты, т.е. такую строку он примет нормально:
`select t from Product t  where t.category.id=2  ORDER BY count(t.id) DESC`
createNativeQuery метод так же прекрасно принимает первую строку(чуть переделанную под названия колонок в бд, а не в сущности), но надо использовать именно createQuery метод.
Вопрос: как можно реализовать `ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(..) ..) в createQuery?`

Comment: А зачем так сложно? Вставте суб-запрос как поле в основной запрос и сортируйте.  Или соедините таблицы.

Comment: @0xdb пробовал делать `select t, (select oi.id from OrderItem oi where oi.product.id = t.id) as cc from Product t group by t.id ORDER BY count(cc) ASC` , `query` создается, но при получение `getResultSet()` - вылетает ошибка, что в `Product` нет поля `cc`

Comment: @0xdb `entityManager` пытается сразу собрать объекты класса `Product`, быть может можно это как-то задизейблить? или по-другому обойти?

Comment: @НикитаКрагель какую СУБД используете?

Comment: @VitalyKolyada Postgres

Comment: @НикитаКрагель почему у вас в именах столбцов точки «.»? Например  , `t.category.id` и `oi.product.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой запрос должен работать:

```
SELECT t
    ,(SELECT COUNT(oi.id)
      FROM OrderItem oi
      WHERE oi.product.id = t.id) AS cc
FROM Product t
ORDER BY cc ASC
```

Comment: это не nativeQuery, а просто Query.. в нее подставляются данные и имена, которые в классах сущностей прописаны, поэтому там oi.product.id